# Access Sharepoint On-Prem in another VM

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, azure, virtual-machine

I have a SP 2013 installed in one VM and I want to access the sites to another VM, is it possible?

Comment: Are the VMs on the same network?

Comment: yes both my VMs can ping each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible you need to either create DNS entry (if you have it on your network) or update the host file on VM2 with the details of your SP web app and IP of VM1.

host file is located in Windows\system32\drivers\etc